# How do I delete files using the Gutmann Process?

Tags: 16.04, delete

I've been trying to delete some files, large ones in particular, to help smoothen out my system, Is there any command or programm that deletes files via the Gutmann Process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two tools in the official repositories that allow you to overwrite files using the Gutmann method:

- #### `scrub`:

  Install it using `sudo apt-get install scrub`.

  Use it like `scrub -p gutmann /PATH/TO/FILE_TO_ERASE`
- #### The `secure-delete` tools suite:

  Install it using `sudo apt-get install secure-delete`.

  This package contains the tools `srm` (erase files), `sfree` (erase free disk space), `sswap` (erase swap) and `sdmem` (erase RAM).

  All of the tools use the Gutmann method. Find more about each of them by typing
  `man COMMANDNAME`.

  To erase a file, use it like `srm /PATH/TO/FILE_TO_ERASE`.

---

## Warning:

Modern file systems and hardware make secure erasure of files very hard. There are a few cases where even after a seemingly secure wipe of a file, remaining data fragments may still persist on the disk. This includes (no complete list):

- SSDs can not be securely wiped on a file by file base. They contain a wear level controller that distributes write access evenly over all memory cells of the device, so if you tell it to overwrite all clusters occupied of a file, the actual hardware writes may occur on completely unrelated cells, leaving the original data untouched.
- HDD caches improve speed of modern HDDs, but there's also no guarantee that all of its contents are securely deleted and especially that all write commands were performed immediately as instructed. They might get cached by the HDD and performed later, maybe even skipping consecutive writes to the same sectors and only performing the last one...(?)
- Journaling file systems like `ext4` may log data writes in a special invisible journal file before performing the actual write in the data section of the partition. This is to ensure that in case of e.g. power failure or a crash, the data which was about to get written can be restored and the file system is not left in a corrupt state. However, depending on the mount options, there can be either only file metadata (Ubuntu default) or even real data fragments left in the journal which do not get securely erased.
- ...

Answer (score 1):

The built-in command to do that is `shred`. It is part of the Gnu CoreUtils, and thus already installed.

> shred: Remove files more securely
>
> shred overwrites devices or files, to help prevent even very expensive
>   hardware from recovering the data.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shred-invocation.html, which mentions Peter Gutmann's paper, or see `man shred`.

Comment: `shred` does not implement the Gutmann method itself. You might maybe manually reproduce this method by running multiple `shred` commands without deleting the file, but that would be a hassle.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method), `shred` is an implementation of the Gutmann method.

Comment: In such cases, I rather trust the manpage than a Wikipedia article. And the man page does not mention Gutmann with a single word. Instead it describes a `-n` parameter with which you can specify the number of iterations. Its default is 3 overwriting passes, which is far away from the Gutmann method with 35 passes.